# Linked List - Head stays NULL (C++)

Tags: c++, null, linked-list

I'm reading from a file. The thing is that `NodePTR Ptr` gets corretly linked but `Head` stays `NULL`.

```
template <typename ElementoPTR, typename Element, typename DetallePTR, typename Detail, typename Node, typename NodePTR>
void Arreglo<ElementoPTR, Element, DetallePTR, Detail, Node, NodePTR>::Registro(ifstream &entrada)
{
NodePTR Ptr = Head;
entrada >> Length;

for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++, Ptr = Ptr->Next) {
    Ptr = new Node;
    entrada >> Ptr->Dealer.CompanyName 
        >> Ptr->Dealer.AmountModels;

    Ptr->Dealer.Modelo = new Detail[Ptr->Dealer.AmountModels];

    for (int j = 0; j < Ptr->Dealer.AmountModels; j++)
        entrada >> Ptr->Dealer.Modelo[j].ModelName >> Ptr->Dealer.Modelo[j].Sales;

    }
}
```

Comment: What is `Head` definition ?

Comment: So if you don't want `Head` to stay `NULL`, set it to something else? And you haven't provided enough information to figure out what's happening.

Comment: You never actually _assign_ the underlying value of the `Head` pointer - just changing `Ptr` wouldn't do the trick.

Comment: Whats wrong with std::vector? Its for learning purposes?

Comment: Did not have time yesterday to update the question. I realized for myself that was what @willywonka_dailyblah said. I changed the function and it's working now. But in reverse order :/

Comment: @Manu343726 `std::vector` is not a _linked_ _list_, it's an array.

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah congratulations... Of course I know that. What I mean is that 1) There are containers on the standard library, and 2) dynamic arrays perform far better than linked lists, so a linked list should never be your preferred container

Comment: Your logic is flawed. Your pointer first points to `Head` then it points to a `new Node` and now you are concluding that your pointer is still pointing to `Head`